# How can i load and display files (such as images, videos and pdf documents) in Google Chrome v.73 from LAN

Tags: file, google-chrome, url, lan, file-sharing

I'm building a web application that is supposed to take files from wherever in the LAN and display the content of those files. The application also uses a javascript library for generating embed objects to preview the files, if they are pdf. 
The problem is that i can not successfully seem to link to those files, be them images, documents or videos. 
The url is either formatted by Google Chrome by prefixing it with the address to the local web page, or interprets it as a local file and denies access to load it, or throws a connection time out if i manually prefix the file urls with http://lan-server....

As I said i tried formatting the urls to these files (the ones on the lan machines) in different ways, but none of them work.

Here is an example of an to a file in LAN

```
http://is-something/Subfolder/test/image.png
```

This one gives a timeout error

Here is another one

```
\\is-something/Subfolder/test/image.png
```

This one is prefixed with the address of the current webpage (http://localhost...)

I also tried using file:// way to access the files but it seems this only works for the local machine

So what i would want is a way to acces the files that i spoke about. 
I need to use them in html elements for the src attribute, as well as in the css rules (for background url).

Comment: Can Chrome open that `http://` URL directly?

Comment: Not exactly. I get a connection timeout error: ```net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT```. By trying to access it with an url of this kind it works in a new tab but not in the already loaded page: ```file://is-something/Subfolder/test/image.png```